# How do I insert user input variables into same spot in vector<string>?

Tags: c++11, vector

//Main driver

```
int main(){
```

//If I run the code below.

```
    vector<string> A = {"My name is Muzaib.\n Hello"};
    cout << A[0];
```

//It will print My name is Muzaib

//  Hello

//But what I want to know is how do I do the same but with user input?

```
string name, age;
cout << "Enter name: ";
getline(cin,name);
cout << "\nEnter age: ";
getline(cin,age);
vector<string> B = {"name \n age"}  //remember I want it in the same spot.
cout << B[0]
```

​    return 0;
}

Comment: Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you want to build a string from `name + '\n' + age`, so:

```
std::vector<std::string> B = {name + '\n' + age};
```

I recommend storing the name and age as separate entities though. Example:

```
struct foo {
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& f) {
    return os << f.name << '\n' << f.age;
}

std::vector<foo> B = {{name, std::stoi(age)}};
std::cout << B[0] << '\n';
```