# why my code does not work when I put Variables inside vector with + operand

Tags: string, class, c++11, vector

//This Code WORKS.

//Main driver

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, age;

    name = "Muzaib";
    age = "16";

    std::vector<std::string> B = {name + "\n" + age + "lll" + '\n'};
    B.push_back(name + '\n' + age);
    cout << B[0];
     cout << B[1];
    return 0;
}
```

//This Code DOES NOT WORK.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
```

//Doctor class

```
class Doctor : public Hospital
{
    protected:
        std::vector<std::string> doctors;               //contains list of doctors.
        string Docname;
        int Docage;
        string Docgender;
        string specialty;

    public:
        Doctor();                       //Constructor
        void listDoctors();
        void addDoctor();
        void removeDoctor();
    
};
```

// Allows user to add doctor to the list.

```
void Doctor::addDoctor()
{
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter Doctors name: ";
    getline(cin, Docname);
    cout << "\nEnter Soctors age: ";
    cin >> Docage;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\nEnter Doctors gender";
    getline(cin, Docgender);
    cout << "\nEnter Doctors specialty: ";
    getline(cin, specialty);
```

//This line of code is giving me the following error: [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'std::basic_string' and 'int')
I do not get any errors on the other program.

```
    doctors.push_back(Docname + '\n' + "Age: " + Docage + '\n' + "Gender: " + Docgender + '\n' 
    + "Specialty: " + specialty);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69729646/13421519   This is the link to where I learned how to do this.

Comment: Basically, I am just trying to put all of that information in the same address of the vector.

Comment: This has nothing to do with vectors. `std::string s = "hello"; int x = 42; s + x;` would already reproduce the error. As the error message clearly says, you cannot concatenate a string and an int. Convert the number to string first, as in `... + std::to_string(Docage) + ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a try with below code:

```cpp
doctors.push_back(Docname + '\n' + "Age: " + std::to_string(Docage) + '\n' + "Gender: " + Docgender + '\n' + "Specialty: " + specialty);
```

`Docage` is of type `int`, so it first must be converted to the `string` type
in order to be able to concatenate the value with the other strings.